# SQL Server 2008 Express edition download package

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to download SQL Server 2008 Express edition. I am downloading from http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/, but cannot find a standalone install package. I can only find a install package with Microsoft Web Platform Installer, the installer will access internet to download and then install SQL Server 2008 Express.

I need to find a standalone install package so that I just need to download once from internet and can copy to other machines which do no need to access internet. Where to find a standalone install package which could be used without internet environment?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/06/15/installing-sql-server-2008-guidance.aspx) what you need? It was linked from the bottom of the [SQL Server Express Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/).

Comment: Cool, this is what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7522A683-4CB2-454E-B908-E805E9BD4E28&displaylang=en