# where to find SQL Server 2008 Express multi-language install package?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to find SQL Server 2008 Express multi-language install package, e.g. Japanes version installation package, Chinese version installation package, Korean version installation package. But from  http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/, I cannot find a standalone install package. I can only find a install package with Microsoft Web Platform Installer, the installer will access internet to download and then install SQL Server 2008 Express.

I need to find a standalone multi-language install package so that I just need to download once from internet and can copy to other machines which do no need to access internet. Where to find a standalone install package which could be used without internet environment?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this duplicate [SQL Server 2008 Express edition download package](https://serverfault.com/questions/87279/sql-server-2008-express-edition-download-package) and check the link from the non-answer.

Edit: Based on the question in your comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336

Comment: Seems this link only contains very basic features of SQL Server Express, what I need is full function -- "Runtime with Advanced Services" type of SQL Server 2008 Express. http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/

Any ideas where to download a full function multi-language SQL Server 2008 Express?

Comment: Please see my edited answer

Comment: Cool, question answered!